# How to mention Expire Header and Compression for IIS 6 in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, iis-6

I need to specify the Expire Header and enable Compression for static files such as images, css and js in order to optimize my site. My web app is hosted in IIS 6 with shared server. Since, this is a shared server, so I don't have access to IIS manager. So, the only option, I have is play with "web.config".

Technologies which I am using is Asp.Net MVC 2.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in IIS 6 through Web.config, since config support for such operations were added in IIS7. Ask for assistance from your hosting service provider.